# Creating a VHF technical indicator for Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, technical-indicator

I am trying to create a Vertical Horizontal Filter (VHF) indicator using Excel VBA.

To make things simple, a n-day VHF is calculated as the ratio of the difference between the maximum of n-period highs and the minimum of n-period lows to the sum of past n-period the absolute value of the first difference of the closing prices:

[image]

```
Function VHF(highs As Range, lows As Range, n As Integer, price As Range, price0 As Range)

Dim count As Long
Dim maxhigh As Double
Dim minlow As Double
Dim closediff As Double
Dim day As Integer

maxhigh = Application.Max(highs)
minlow = Application.Min(lows)
day = WorksheetFunction.count(Range(price0, price))
    If day >= n Then
        For j = 2 To n - 1
            closediff = closediff + Abs(price0.Offset(j, 0) - price0.Offset(j - 1, 0))
        Next j
        VHF = (maxhigh - minlow) / closediff
    End If
End Function
```

There is some problem with my VBA code, hopefully someone can help me with it thanks!

Comment: can you provide some sample data and some information on what is the problem you are facing. and one quick question that you are counting price0 and price but doing sum of only one, can it be a problem?

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you checking to see if the `count` function is returning `day=0` or something? Are there other error bounds you can be checking?